# How to rename multiple files by adding a common string at beginning of the files?

Tags: linux, shell-script, rename, command, mv

I have 100 files. I want to add a text 'new' before all the filenames.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

**Example:**

```
file1.txt  --->  new_file1.txt
.
.
.
.
file100.txt  ---> new_file100.txt
```

Please provide a solution to rename multiple files. Here is what I have tried. But this is not a better solution.

```
 
bala@SMS:~/test1$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bala bala 0 Aug 31 19:10 file1.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bala bala 0 Aug 31 19:10 file2.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bala bala 0 Aug 31 19:10 file3.txt
bala@SMS:~/test1$ mv file1.txt new_file1.txt
bala@SMS:~/test1$ mv file2.txt new_file2.txt
bala@SMS:~/test1$ mv file3.txt new_file3.txt
bala@SMS:~/test1$ ls
new_file1.txt  new_file2.txt  new_file3.txt
bala@SMS:~/test1$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use loop to change filename of multiple files:

```
for file in *
do
    mv -v ${file} new_${file}
done
```

The same code in one line:

```
for file in *; do mv -v ${file} new_${file}; done
```

Comment: I would change that to `for file in "/path/to/files/file*.txt"` just to avoid this running a muck in the wrong directory.

Comment: ` bala@SMS:~/test1$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bala bala  0 Aug 31 19:47 file1.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bala bala  0 Aug 31 19:47 file2.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bala bala  0 Aug 31 19:47 file3.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bala bala 49 Aug 31 19:41 new_test.sh
bala@SMS:~/test1$ sh new_test.sh 
‘file1.txt’ -> ‘new_file1.txt’
‘file2.txt’ -> ‘new_file2.txt’
‘file3.txt’ -> ‘new_file3.txt’
‘new_test.sh’ -> ‘new_new_test.sh’
bala@SMS:~/test1$ ls
new_file1.txt  new_file2.txt  new_file3.txt  new_new_test.sh
bala@SMS:~/test1$ `

Comment: It's hard to read what you pasted there but I suppose it's working

Answer (score 2):

```
$ find . -type f -name "file*.txt" -execdir mv {} new_{} \;
```

This will find all regular files in the current directory (or below) that have names that matches the pattern `file*.txt`, and rename these by adding the prefix `new_` to their names.

This requires a `find` that understands `-execdir` (most modern `find` implementations do). The `-execdir` option works like `-exec` but executes the utility (`mv`) in the directory of the found thing. Also, `{}` will contain the basename of the found thing.

To limit to the current directory *only*, add `-maxdepth 1` somewhere before `-execdir`.

---

```
bash-4.4$ mkdir dir{1..10}
bash-4.4$ touch dir{1..10}/file{1..10}.txt

bash-4.4$ ls
dir1  dir10 dir2  dir3  dir4  dir5  dir6  dir7  dir8  dir9

bash-4.4$ ls dir5
file1.txt   file2.txt   file4.txt   file6.txt   file8.txt
file10.txt  file3.txt   file5.txt   file7.txt   file9.txt

bash-4.4$ find . -name "file*.txt" -execdir mv {} new_{} \;

bash-4.4$ ls dir5
new_file1.txt    new_file2.txt    new_file4.txt    new_file6.txt    new_file8.txt
new_file10.txt   new_file3.txt    new_file5.txt    new_file7.txt    new_file9.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use rename command; check if you have installed on your system or install it with your OS package manager

```
[root@archy pippo]# rename -h

Usage:
 rename [options] <expression> <replacement> <file>...

Rename files.

Options:
 -v, --verbose    explain what is being done
 -s, --symlink    act on the target of symlinks

 -h, --help     display this help and exit
 -V, --version  output version information and exit

For more details see rename(1).
```

in your case, you have to do this simple substitution

```
[root@archy pippo]# ls -lrta
total 8
drwxr-x--- 6 root root 4096 Aug 31 14:12 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Aug 31 14:12 file1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Aug 31 14:12 file2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Aug 31 14:12 file3.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Aug 31 14:12 file4.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 31 14:24 .
[root@archy pippo]# rename -v file new_file *.txt
`file1.txt' -> `new_file1.txt'
`file2.txt' -> `new_file2.txt'
`file3.txt' -> `new_file3.txt'
`file4.txt' -> `new_file4.txt'
[root@archy pippo]# ls -lrta
total 8
drwxr-x--- 6 root root 4096 Aug 31 14:12 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Aug 31 14:12 new_file1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Aug 31 14:12 new_file2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Aug 31 14:12 new_file3.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Aug 31 14:12 new_file4.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 31 14:27 .
[root@archy pippo]#
```

et voilà :)

Comment: sorry.. but it did not work for me. i could see this. --> Bareword "file" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at (eval 1) line 1.

Comment: I believe some systems (Debian included?) have a different (`perl`-related?) tool available as `rename`, which does not accept the syntax in @WesT_Tale's answer.

Comment: [An answer at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743284/batch-rename-files/18743354#18743354) has an example of the invocation for that other `rename` tool.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mv` with [Brace Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion) within a loop.

```
for N in {1..100}; do
     mv {,new_}file$N.txt
done
```

Before running the `mv` command, shell will expand it to the command like this for each file where `$N` will substitute with corresponding sequence number.

```
mv file$N.txt new_file$N.txt
```

so this appending a *prefix* to the fileName.