# Adding a suffix to many files while preserving the extensions

Tags: rename

I have a directory `~/mydir/` with many files. Some of these files are

```
~/mydir/foo.py
~/mydir/foo.tex
~/mydir/foo.pdf
~/mydir/foo.log
```

I'd like to change any file in `~/mydir/` whose base name is `foo` to `foo-bar`. So, the files above should be renamed as

```
~/mydir/foo-bar.py
~/mydir/foo-bar.tex
~/mydir/foo-bar.pdf
~/mydir/foo-bar.log
```

I am not worried about the new file names conflicting with existing files (`$ ls ~/mydir/foo-bar*` returns nothing).

It seems like this should be easy to do in bash, but I can't figure it out.

Is there a simple script to accomplish this task?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389514/how-to-rename-multiple-files-by-adding-a-common-string-at-beginning-of-the-files (slightly different question, but the answers there should be useful too)

Answer (score 3):

If your distribution uses (or offers) the perl version of rename (Debian and most derivatives do):

```
cd mydir
rename 's/\.([^.]+)$/-bar.$1/
```

I know some distributions (I don't remember which it was) offers it as `prename`.

Comment: Is there any still-supported distribution that offers it as `rename` but not as `prename`? In Debian `rename` has been a symlink to `prename` since 2008.

Answer (score 3):

This could be done with `mv`:

```
for name in ./foo*; do mv "$name" "${name/foo/foo-bar}"; done
```

For example:

```
[devuser@machine test]$ touch foo.log foo.pdf foo.tex foo.py
[devuser@machine test]$ ls
foo.log  foo.pdf  foo.py  foo.tex
[devuser@machine test]$ for name in ./foo*; do mv "$name" "${name/foo/foo-bar}"; done
[devuser@machine test]$ ls
foo-bar.log  foo-bar.pdf  foo-bar.py  foo-bar.tex
```